# Is there a linux command to copy a file into another file at a specific point?

Tags: linux, file, merge-file

In linux can you copy one file into another file at a specific line(using a terminal command)?

Ex.
File 1:

```
this is 
file 1
```

File 2:

```
this is
file 2
```

New File:

```
this is
this is
file 2
file 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use [paste](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste)

```
$ cat file1 
this is
file 1
$ cat file2
this is
file 2
$ paste -d '\n' file2 file1 > new_file
$ cat new_file 
this is
this is
file 2
file 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any native command to do this, but you could do it at least a couple of ways.

```
1a. file chunk1 = head _n_ lines of file 1
1b. file chunk2 = tail _m_ lines of file 1
1c. cat chunk1 file_2 chunk2 > new_file
```

or write a simple script (e.g., in Perl) to

```
2a. read _n_ lines of file 1 and write them out to new_file
2b. read file 2 and write it out to new_file
2c. finish reading remaining lines of file 1 and write them out to new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "`head --lines=$NLINES input1 >output`" to output the first `$NLINES`
2. Use "`cat input2 >>output`" to insert the second file
3. Use "`tail --lines=+$[NLINES+1] input1 >>output`" to output the remaining lines